# How naga sadhus reach to kumba mela place?

Tags: yoga, saint, kumbh-mela

I have read this in a facebook post, I felt it as a puzzle and thought to ask here.

We all know that naga sadhus won't wear cloths, but how they reach to kumba mela place?

If those many people are walking on road , or travelling in buses or trains, we would have seen them or news channels have shown them that they are travelling to kumbha mela place, but nothing happened?

That post is claiming that naga sadhus have some special skills ( similar to nano technology) , post seems to be funny, but is that real that they travel invisibly to the place they wanted
Nano technology. If yes, then how can a person become naga sadhu, if it is difficult to know where they are on earth?